# Are file systems consistent between docker containers with delegated consistency?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am using the following commands to create several containers sharing the same directory with the host using delegated consistency:

```sh
docker run -v `pwd`:/opt/dir:cached alpine myCmd1
docker run -v `pwd`:/opt/dir:cached alpine myCmd2
...
```

From the [doc. about shared filesystems for Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#performance-implications-of-host-container-file-system-consistency), when using the delegated consistency between the host and a container, the container’s view is authoritative (permit delays before updates on the container appear in the host).

Should I expect the same consistency between containers as well? Or they have an identical view of the mount at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using delegated mode, all containers should have the same view of a given bind mount (assuming they are on the same runtime).

([Docker documentation of delegated semantics](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#delegated))

> All containers hosted by the same runtime *must* share a consistent cache of the mount.